# Jenkins "Build with Parameters" with Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, parameters

I have a Jenkins job which I have **parameterized** with a parameter `param_foo`, and set some default value for the parameter. I can correctly see and edit the parameter when I click on the `Build with parameters` option on the job which replaced the "Build" option due to change in settings.

I have a `build.gradle` in my project, and this is where I want to read the parameter. I tried these:

```
def paramFooProp = System.getProperty('param_foo');
def paramFooEnv = System.getenv('param_foo');
```

Both of these are not working.

How do I read the parameter values in my `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

when you run your gradle  task just add the parameter

```
gradle build -PparamFooProp =${param_foo}
```

Comment: I have a task in `build.gradle` that is calling a rest endpoint that needs the param. Not sure how your solution will work. The Jenkins job already calls the gradle task with the param.